# Angular ng-repeat pass item to function with parent data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass the {{trade}} with its parent to the open function.

when i click the li I want the parent(ticker) data and the child(trade) data displayed in an alert box.

here is the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/QuG8NcOvPKVAnfRNYwlx?p=preview

html:

```
<table ng-controller = "TickerListCtrl">
<thead>
  <th>Symbol</th>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="ticker in tickers">
  <tr ng-click="showTrades(ticker)">
      <td>{{ticker.Ticker}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-show="ticker.showTrades">
      <td colspan="2">
        <ul ng-repeat="trade in ticker.trades">
          <li ng-click="open(trade)">{{trade}}</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

tickers:

```
  $scope.tickers = [
{
    "Ticker": "4512",
    "TradeCount": "91",
    "trades" :
      [{
        "one": "this one",
        "two": "this two",
        "three": "this three"
      },
      {
        "one": "this one",
        "two": "this two",
        "three": "this three"
      },
      {
        "one": "this one",
        "two": "this two",
        "three": "this three"
      },
      {
        "one": "this one",
        "two": "this two",
        "three": "this three"
      },
      {
        "one": "this one",
        "two": "this two",
        "three": "this three"
      },
      {
        "one": "this one",
        "two": "this two",
        "three": "this three"
      },
      {
        "one": "this one",
        "two": "this two",
        "three": "this three"
      }]
}]
```

Comment: whats is your question ? give any example.

Comment: I guess you want to do `ng-click="open(ticker);"` instead.

Comment: (ticker) would give me all of the trades. I only want the selected trade and it's parents returned.

Comment: @NitishKumar i created a plunker with the code that reflect the issue

Comment: did you mean something like that: http://plnkr.co/edit/I5jlZeu6ekVPnZEB9AJp ... very unclear question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.open = function (trade) {
   alert(ticker.Ticker);
};
```

Replace To :

```
 $scope.open = function (ticker, trade) {
  var myObj = {};
  myObj['Ticker'] = ticker['Ticker'];
  myObj['TradeCount'] = ticker['TradeCount'];
  delete trade['$$hashKey'];
  myObj['trades'] = trade;

 alert(JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

};

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/RRkJ7ybvnEQ3tWdmvL1T)

Comment: I need to call the entire tree so i can pass it to another controller. I am able to call individual elements

Comment: just the tree that refers to the trade selected

Comment: like for one trade :{
        "Ticker": "1190",
        "TradeCount": "91",
        "trades" :
          {
            "one": "this one",
            "two": "this two",
            "three": "this three"
          }
    }

Comment: the data model wasn't making the issue clear so i updated the it: http://plnkr.co/edit/5anEAKfbcPvFGmpU5bco?p=preview

i am tryin to return the parent data and the selected array data only

Comment: { "Ticker": "1190", "TradeCount": "91", "trades" : { "one": "this one", "two": "this two", "three": "this three" }}

Comment: did you look at the data model i updated? http://plnkr.co/edit/QuG8NcOvPKVAnfRNYwlx?p=preview

i just want the parent and the selected trade { "Ticker": "1190", "TradeCount": "91", "trades" : { "one": "this one", "two": "this two", "three": "this three" }}  without altering the original objects since they are being used on the page still.

Comment: i appreciate your help and i am sorry if my question is not clear. I just want the parent and the selected data so i can pass it to another controller

Comment: means selected trade object

Comment: parent has multiple children. i just want the parent(with data) and the one child{{trade}}(with data) passed to the open function OR created in the open function. the parent object cannot be altered since it is being used on the page in other models